# Display image in rdlc report

Tags: asp.net, rdlc

I used a matrix in rdlc report to display image horizontally.
When there is multiple images, three of them are displayed on the first page and the last one is displayed on another page

In rdlc report, how would I display images on multiple rows instead of on multiple pages?

Comment: Please enter a example of your code to better explain your case and so that we can help you. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: But its all about designing side..Not a code.I use pgadmin and return a table who have image name and path and i use for loop to display them.

Comment: I'm creating a multrow rdlc report where i need to display pictures related to an item.
Let's say the item have 5 different pictures and i need to display 3 pictures per row.

Her's my example on how i wish to display pictures of the item:                            
**Column1     :  Image1.png          Image2.png          Image3.png       
Column2     :  Image4.png          Image5.png**